# Write proof that a matrix $N\times N$ with all values greater than 5 and $\vec x,\vec y$ being stochastic then $\sum \vec xA\vec y^T\ge 5$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Better way to write a proof that a matrix $N\times N$ with all values greater than 5 and $\vec x,\vec y$ being stochastic then $\sum \vec xA\vec y^T\ge 5$

I have a proof for this but it's a bit wordy

"Since all indexes in A are at least 5 then any stochastic vector because it sums to 1, by property of matrix multiplication multiplied by A must create a vector of elements $\ge$5, then since x is another stochastic vector that sums to 5, the sum of that times a vector where every element is greater or equal to 5 will be greater than or equal to 5 as well."

Is there a more elegant way to write this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\sum \vec xA\vec y^T$? Do you mean $\vec xA\vec y^T$? If so, this is just $\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}x_iy_j\ge \sum_{i,j}5x_iy_j=5\sum_ix_i\sum_jy_j=5$.

Comment: Note that your proof would seem to imply $6\cdot 2 + 10\cdot (-1) \geq 5.$  It's also important to use the assumption that the entries of a stochastic vector are non-negative in your proof.

Comment: @BrianMoehring isn't that implied? You can't have a negative probability right?

Comment: @TonyK it means the sum of the vector you get at the end. So your interpretation is correct. I also believe for your equation you're missing a transpose in there.

Comment: But you don't get a vector at the end, you just get a scalar. (And I don't see where I'm missing a transpose $-$ all the elements in my equation are scalars.)

Comment: It is part of the definition of "stochastic vector," certainly.  However, you have written "any stochastic vector because it sums to 1, by property of matrix multiplication multiplied by A must create a vector of elements ≥5" -- The phrase "because it sums to 1" is either false ("this is the reason the next statement follows") or insufficient ("here is this fact, but you'll have to find another similar fact to prove the next statement").  You might skip details in higher-level proofs, but you shouldn't skip some details and include others which are at the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec e=(1,1,\ldots,1)$. By assumption, $A\ge5\vec e^T\vec e$ entrywise. Therefore
$$
\vec xA\vec y^T\ge \vec x(5\vec e^T\vec e)\vec y^T=5(\vec x\,\vec e^T)(\vec e\,\vec y^T)=5.
$$

Comment: why is $\vec e$ all 1s? It should sum to one if it's a stochastic vector. Unless I'm misinterpreting what e is

Comment: @user8714896 $\vec e$ is not a stochastic vector. It is defined to be a vector of ones.

Comment: How does that help prove in the case of x and y being stochastic vectors?

Comment: @user8714896 Please read the proof.